# Не могу сортировать массив в стейте Redux Toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

Стек: react, redux toolkit

Имеется следующая типизация глобал стейта:

```js
export type TodoItem = {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  order: number;
  content: string;
  isChecked: boolean;
};

export type Board = {
  title: string;
  id: string;
  order: number;
  items: TodoItem[];
};

export type State = {
  boards: Board[];
  settings?: any;
};
```

Здесь важно заметить то, что массив todo находится в массиве boards. Полагаю во вложенности и заключается проблема.
Я создал экшен который меняет местами (свойство order) todo на board'е. Пытаюсь начать сортировку, но она не работает.
Код экшена ниже:

```js
changeOrders: (state, action: PayloadAction<[currentTodo: TodoItem, eventTodo: TodoItem]>) => {
      const sortFunc = (a: TodoItem | Board, b: TodoItem | Board) => {
        return a.order - b.order;
      };
      state.boards.map((board) =>
        board.items
          .map((todo) => {
            if (todo.id === action.payload[0].id) {
              return { ...todo, order: action.payload[1].order };
            }
            if (todo.id === action.payload[1].id) {
              return { ...todo, order: action.payload[0].order };
            } else return todo;
          })
          .sort(sortFunc),
      );
    },
```

Ожидаемая реакция - стейт обновляется, сортируется, перерендеривается.
У меня же - стейт не обновляется, стейт не сохраняет сортировку, не перерендеривается.

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что ничего не происходит? То что не обновляется стейт, не говорит о том, что сортировка не произошла.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется проблема в том, что результат `map()` не используется. Т.к. вы используете Redux Toolkit, то вам вам стоит сделать `state.boards = state.boards.map(...)`